# Java 8 Filtering with condition and collecting custom Map

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have some collection `List<Map<String, Object>>` which need to be filtered optionally with Java 8 lambda expressions. 
I will receive JSON object with flags which filtering criteria have to be applied. If JSON object is not received, then no filtering is needed.

```
protected List<Map<String, Object>> populate(List<SomeObject> someObjects, String string) {
    taskList.stream()
            // How to put condition here? Ho to skip filter if no filter oprions are received?
            .filter(someObject -> (if(string != null) someobject.getName == string))
           // The second problem is to collect custom map like
            .collect(Collectors.toMap("customField1"), someObject.getName()) ... // I need somehow put some additional custom fields here
}
```

Now I'm collecting custom map like that:

```
Map<String, Object> someMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
someMap.put("someCustomField1", someObject.field1());
someMap.put("someCustomField2", someObject.field2());
someMap.put("someCustomField3", someObject.field3());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just check, whether you need to apply the filter or not and then use the `filter` method or don't use it:

```
protected List<Map<String, Object>> populate(List<SomeObject> someObjects, String string) {
    Stream<SomeObject> stream = someObjects.stream();
    if (string != null) {
         stream = stream.filter(s -> string.equals(s.getName()));
    }
    return stream.map(someObject -> {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("someCustomField1", someObject.Field1());
        map.put("someCustomField2", someObject.Field2());
        map.put("someCustomField3", someObject.Field3());
        return map;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:

```
protected List<Map<String, Object>> populate(List<SomeObject> someObjects, String string) {
    return someObjects.stream()
            .filter(someObject -> string == null || string.equals(someObject.getName()))
            .map(someObject -> 
              new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
                    put("someCustomField1", someObject.Field1());
                    put("someCustomField2", someObject.Field2());
                    put("someCustomField3", someObject.Field3());
              }})
            .collect(Collectors.toList()) ;
}
```

Comment: In Java 9, you can replace the awful inner class construction with Map.of().

Comment: @BrianGoetz nice to 'meet' you! I read Java concurrency in practice and I love it!

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera or dont wait for java-9 and use guava ImmutableMap.of()

Comment: @Brian Goetz: the question’s code uses a `LinkedHashMap` and I suppose, the result of `Map.of(…)` won’t provide the same ordered’ness.